# How to implement a login with retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am developing an app with retrofit.
I am new to developing a login with retrofit.

My JSON code for the login:

```
{
        "login": [
            {
                "sessionid": 12973,
                "responsetypes": "success"
            }
        ]
    }
```

How do I implement login for this type of JSON?
Following is my code: it gives error to onresponse method.how do i solve this?

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

```
private AppCompatButton btn_login;
private EditText et_email,et_password;
private TextView tv_register;
private ProgressBar progress;
private SharedPreferences pref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    pref = LoginActivity.this.getPreferences(0);

    btn_login = (AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    tv_register = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_register);
    et_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    et_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);

    progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_register.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.tv_register:
            goToRegister();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_login:
            String email = et_email.getText().toString();
            String password = et_password.getText().toString();

            if(!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loginProcess(email,password);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Fields are empty !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;

    }
}
private void loginProcess(String userID,String password){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(userID);
    user.setPassword(password);
    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.LOGIN_OPERATION);
    request.setUser(user);
    Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

    response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, resp.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,true);

                editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,resp.getUser().getEmail());
             //   editor.putString(Constants.NAME,resp.getUser().getName());
                editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,resp.getUser().getUnique_id());
                editor.apply();
                goToProfile();

            }
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
            //Snackbar.make(getV, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}

private void goToRegister(){

    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

private void goToProfile(){

    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

//
public interface RequestInterface {

```
@POST("ypAndroid/api/")
Call<ServerResponse> operation(@Body ServerRequest request);
```

}

public class Constants {

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com/";
public static final String REG_URL = "http://www.example.com/";
public static final String REGISTER_OPERATION = "register";
public static final String LOGIN_OPERATION = "login";
public static final String CHANGE_PASSWORD_OPERATION = "chgPass";

public static final String SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String FAILURE = "failure";
public static final String IS_LOGGED_IN = "isLoggedIn";

public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String EMAIL = "userID";
public static final String UNIQUE_ID = "sessionid";

public static final String TAG = "Demo";
```

}

//
public class ServerRequest {

```
private String operation;
private User user;

public void setOperation(String operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

}

//public class ServerResponse {

```
private String result;
private String message;
private User user;

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

}

//

public class Login {

```
@SerializedName("sessionid")
@Expose
private Integer sessionid;
@SerializedName("responsetypes")
@Expose
private String responsetypes;

public Integer getSessionid() {
    return sessionid;
}

public void setSessionid(Integer sessionid) {
    this.sessionid = sessionid;
}

public String getResponsetypes() {
    return responsetypes;
}

public void setResponsetypes(String responsetypes) {
    this.responsetypes = responsetypes;
}
```

}

Comment: share your tried code....

Comment: I have added code please suggest me?

Comment: Please post the code for ServerResponse

Comment: i have added code for ServerResponse

Comment: Do accept the answers that work for you! :)

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your code, refer to step 2 of the process and change your ServerResponse Class. You're not mapping the response correctly.

You need to take the following steps to implement any kind of API in retrofit:

1. Make an interface defining your end which includes the response and request.

   ```
   public interface MyClient { 
   @FromUrlEncoded 
   @POST("your/login/end/point/")
   Call<RequestClass> login(@String("username") String username, other post parameters);
   }
   ```
2. Make a response POJO Class. It'll be RequestClass that I have mentioned above. You can create it from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ .
3. Make a REST Client
   You can make a Rest Client for your API as follows :

   ```
   String API_BASE_URL = "https://your.base.url/";

   OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

   Retrofit.Builder builder =  
   new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
           .addConverterFactory(
               GsonConverterFactory.create()
           );

   Retrofit retrofit =  builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();

   RestClient client =  retrofit.create(MyClient.class);
   ```
4. Apply it where you want to send the request to server.

   ```
   // Create a very simple REST adapter which points the GitHub API endpoint.
   RestClient client =  retrofit.create(GitHubClient.class);

   // Call the API
   Call<ResponseClass> call =  client.login(parameter_of_login_call);

   call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseClass>() {  
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<ResponseClass> call, Response<ResponseClass> response) {
   // The network call was a success and we got a response
   // implement the what needs to be done here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseClass> call, Throwable t) {
    // the network call was a failure
    // handle error
    }
    });
   ```

Comment: Go through this guide step by step and you'll be able to implement your code very easily

Comment: Now i have edited the question, i have added response please suggest me how do i login?

Comment: Go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and put your server response code. You'll get the correct POJO classes which will be ServerResponse class.

Comment: What is RestClient used in the above code ? @KavachChandra